# Component.move(int,int) is deprecated but still used

Tags: java, awt, move, deprecated

Trying to create a click and drag GUI, I accidentally overwrote `Component.move`in my subclass. Doing that caused a stack overflow whenever `Component.setLocation` was called.

After renaming my move method this didn't happen. I found out that I had overwritten `move` and that it gets called by `setLocation`.

However, the Oracle documentation states that `move` was deprecated long ago. Why is it then still used by `setLocation`? Doesn't that mean that either `setLocation` is deprecated as well or `move` isn't?

Answer (score 0):

any api annotated as `@Deprecated` means it is will be removed in future version. the deprecated api is from the clients' point of view not the vendor. if `move` method remove in future, the vendor can free to change the  `setLocation` but the client can't run without update the code to call the `new` api.

`setLocation` not annotated with `@Deprecated` means you can glad to run the program without change anything in future jdk.

Answer (score 0):

Deprecated methods may still exist to support backwards compatibility of an application or to tell the developer that the method is going to be removed in a future release of the library.

A deprecated method itself is still fully functional and works, but it's an indication that there is a different, preferrable way of doing the same thing.

Other methods, often with different functionality, who are still using the deprecated method are not necessarily deprecated themselves. Their implementation may be outdated, but the API is not.